# shell string bad substitution

Tags: string, shell, substitution

I'm new to shell programming. I intend to get directory name after zip file was extracted. The print statement of it is

```
$test.sh helloworld.zip
helloworld
```

Let's take a look at test.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
length=echo `expr index "$1" .zip`
a=$1    
echo $(a:0:length}
```

However I got the Bad substitution error from the compiler.

And when I mention about 'shell'.I just talking about shell for I don't know the difference between bash or the others.I just using Ubuntu 10.04 and using the terminal. (I am using bash.)

Comment: what is your argument to the script, i.e. the value of $1? Please edit this information INTO your message above, and not as a reply to my comment. try surrounding all references to $1 in dbl-quotes, i.e. `echo "$1"`, etc. Good luck!

Comment: What did you expext with `${a:0}` ?

Comment: try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Comment: Wow,add #! /bin/bash works.WHY?What's the difference between using #! /bin/bash and #! /bin/sh

Comment: They are different shells that implement different features. Even if `/bin/sh` is bash, it is executed as if `--posix` was used, which disables some bash features.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` may be `dash` (Debian Almquist Shell), and that hews to the POSIX standard very closely, and doesn't support Bash-only extensions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your shell is a sufficiently recent version of `bash`, that [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) notation should work.

In many other shells, it will not work, and a `bad substitution` error is the way the shell says 'You asked for a parameter substitution but it does not make sense to me'.

---

Also, given the script:

```
#! /bin/sh
length=echo `expr index "$1" .zip`
a=$1    
echo $(a:0:length}
```

The second line exports variable `length` with value `echo` for the command that is generated by running `expr index "$1" .zip`.  It does not assign to `length`.  That should be just:

```
length=$(expr index "${1:?}" .zip)
```

where the `${1:?}` notation generates an error if `$1` is not set (if the script is invoked with no arguments).

The last line should be:

```
echo ${a:0:$length}
```

Note that if `$1` holds `filename.zip`, the output of `expr index $1 .zip` is 2, because the letter `i` appears at index 2 in `filename.zip`.  If the intention is to get the base name of the file without the `.zip` extension, then the classic way to do it is:

```
base=$(basename $1 .zip)
```

and the more modern way is:

```
base=${1%.zip}
```

There is a difference; if the name is `/path/to/filename.zip`, the classic output is `filename` and the modern one is `/path/to/filename`.  You can get the classic output with:

```
base=${1%.zip}
base=${base##*/}
```

Or, in the classic version, you can get the path with:

```
base=$(dirname $1)/$(basename $1 .zip)
```

If the file names can contain spaces, you need to think about using double quotes, especially in the invocations of `basename` and `dirname`.

Comment: What is a "sufficiently recent version" ? I'm working with bash 4.2.37 and I'm facing this problem.

Comment: @Simon: it works for me with Bash 3.2.51 (provided with Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks).  It also works with Bash 4.2.25 (provided with Ubuntu 12.04).  For example: `AZ=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; echo ${AZ:10:10}` yields `klmnopqrst` on both systems.  Further, it works OK whether it is Bash run as `bash` or as `sh`.  So, you'd need to elaborate on exactly what you're doing, along the lines of the example I've just given. Note that both values must be numbers.  You could write: `length=10` and `echo ${AZ:10:$length}` but the second `$` is crucial in that notation.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Actually `AZ=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; echo ${AZ:10:10}` yields a `Bad substitution` for me (Bash 4.2.37 - Debian 7.4). I guess I have to dig deeper.

Comment: @Simon: now that is a curious state of affairs.  I guess you're going to need to track down what is in 4.2.37 vs 4.2.25, or something (with no guarantee that your '.25' is the same as 'mine').  [Bash 4.3](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) was released by Gnu 2014-02-26 (4.2 on 2011-02-13).  Maybe try building that?  Otherwise, you may have a regression bug on your hands.  (I just built Bash 4.3 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 while adding this comment — it took a couple of minutes after completing the download — and the AZ-test works cleanly on it.)

Comment: @Simon — it occurs to me five years later that you may be (have been) using `dash` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Could you explain the `.zip)\`.)` part of classic version? Was there any typo? I think it should be `base=$(dirname $1)/$(basename $1).zip`

Comment: @LShi — there is (or was when you commented) a stray backtick which should not be there; indeed, neither the `.` or the final `)` are wanted.  **Thank you!**  It's likely a mistake from originally using backticks instead of `$(…)` notation.  The `.zip` was correctly placed though — `basename` removes the `.zip` suffix from `helloworld.zip`, leaving the directory name `helloworld`.  Placing the `.zip` after the call to `basename` would leave you with `helloworld.zip.zip` as the directory name, which is not plausible.  This assumes that the contents of `helloworld.zip` extract into `helloworld`.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you too! From you I learned `basename` accepts a second argument.

Answer (score 10):

Try running it with bash.

**bash test.sh helloworld.zip**

-likewise-

"try changing the first line to **#!/bin/bash**" as comment-answered by – @shellter

Comment: i was using ```sh test.sh``` and updated ```bash test.sh```. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try that in `bash` :

```
echo $1
len=$(wc -c <<< "$1")
a="${1}.zip"
echo ${a:0:$len}
```

Adapt it to fit your needs.